# Reformat date before echo PHP

Tags: php, date

We all know dates are stored as YYYY-MM-DD. I have a search box that brings up user information including birth dates etc.. how can I reformat the string before it actually echoes it below??:

```
   echo '<br /> Exp. Date: '   .$row['exp_date'];
```

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL accepts dates in that format, but not necessarily stores them like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo '<br /> Exp. Date: ' . date(DATE_RSS, strtotime(row['exp_date']));
```

Where `DATE_RSS` is whatever date format you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your looking for the php function called [date()](http://php.net/date).

string **date** ( string *$format* [, int *$timestamp* = time() ] )

For the $format in the style of your example would be;

- y - As it's the four digit year.
- m - As it's always a two digit month, with leading zero.
- d - As it's always a two digit day, with leading zero.

The php date function does not parse hythens, so you can just add them like so to make the format parameter correct for your function. `$format = 'y-m-d';`.

Now `$timestamp` paramater expects the seconds since the [Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). As we think your currently formatted as a string, we can convert this to seconds with the [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) function. For that it's as simple as doing this, `$timestamp = strtotime($row['exp_date'])`;

Puting this all togeater into one simple function call and outputing the results like you asked is the following code sample.

```
echo '<br /> Exp. Date: ' . date('y-m-d', strtotime($row['exp_date']));
```